# Post request working on postman (status 201) but on angular status 409 (conflict)

Tags: c#, angular, entity-framework, postman, .net-framework-version

I have many to many relationship between Contact entity and Tag entity. When I try to add tag on contact that already exists on some other contact I get status 409 response. On the other hand, in Postman I can add tag without a problem (status 201).

```cs
// POST: api/TagContacts
        [ResponseType(typeof(TagContact))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTagContact(TagContact tagContact)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }


                db.TagContacts.Add(tagContact);


                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = tagContact.ContactID }, tagContact);
        }
```

---

```js
createTagContact(obj: TagContactDTO): Observable<TagContactDTO>{
        return this.http.post<TagContactDTO>(this.URL_TAG_CONTACTS, obj);
    }
```

---

```
 public createTag(){
    if(this.tag === ""){
      return;
    }
    this.api.createTag(new TagDTO(this.tag)).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res.ID);
        console.log(this.getContactId());
        this.api.createTagContact(new TagContactDTO(this.getContactId(), res.ID)).subscribe(
          res => {
            this.getContactTags();
          }
        )
      },
      err => {
        this.api.searchForTagByName(this.tag).subscribe(
          res => {
            this.api.createTagContact(new TagContactDTO(this.getContactId(), res.ID)).subscribe(
              res => {
                this.getContactTags();
              }
            )
          }
        )
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Have you set UseCors policy to allow origin, method and header?

Comment: Yes I have and I solved problem in meantime. Problem occured because I defined argument in backend like 'ID' and in fronted like 'Id'. That is why I got undefined value in Id. Thank you anyway!